# How to define a function that can be directly printed like Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The Date, we all know that once we instantiate it, say

```
var now = new Date();
```

We can directly print *now* as a string, event it is an object

```
console.log(now); //Sun Mar 12 2017 12:48:21...
```

And this will work the same:

```
console.log(Date());
```

How this works? and how do I defined a user function like this?

Comment: give the object prototype a `toString` function

Comment: Even if you override `toString`, most consoles won’t call it. They special-case `Date`.

Comment: yes, I see that ... there's also `valueOf` - but that doesn't cut it either ... you'd have to `console.log(whatever+'')` and that will call `valueOf` it seems, not `toString`

Comment: @JaromandaX: `date.valueOf()` returns a number, so `""+date` must use `.toString()`

Comment: Javascript. Full of inconsistencies

Comment: Thank you guys for concerning my question, I now know that consoles and browsers display Date differently other than normal objects is because they treat Date in a special way.

Answer (score -1):

If you do it this way, you won't be modifying the native `Date` constructor:

```js
var DateConstructor = function() {
  this.date = new Date();
};

DateConstructor.prototype.printDate = function() {
  console.log(this.date);
};

var date = new DateConstructor();

date.printDate();
```

**Edit: March 27**

I think I understand the question now. You're asking: "If the `Date` constructor is returning an object as its instance, why does the object `console.log` as a string? How can I reproduce this with my own constructors?"

It looks like the `Date` constructor doesn't return normal object types. And even though its `typeof` returns `"object"`, it, in some ways, behaves more like the `"string"` type. Strings don't `console.log` as objects, yet they have methods such as `spit` on their prototype.

As far as I know. There's no way to create javascript constructors that return anything other than objects. However, it seems that the native `Date` constructor lives outside this rule.

[Here](http://www.neilstuff.com/winhttp.html#javascript-constructor-value)'s an interesting article about JS constructor returns.

Comment: Thank you for concerning this question, but you haven't got the point of what I asked.